# Best way to broadcast SQL Azure Database for consumption by Ember.js app?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, azure-sql-database

I am working with a team to create an MS Azure hosted web app following the ember.js framework. This app needs to interface with a sql Azure database, and I am wondering what the best way to broadcast that database would be. This needs to be a secured connection.

On the client side, we are looking to use Ember Data to consume JSON output from the Database, but I am confused as to how to make the connection on the server side. Should I be creating a RESTful web service using node.js or Windows Azure Mobile Services?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to expose data via a HTTP server. Ember.js is totally agnostic about server solutions so this can be written in any language you want. If you are writing this server from scratch and can match the semantics of the [sample Adapter included with ember-data](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/) you'll find it works pretty much "out of the box"

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the part that I understand. What I'm trying to figure out is the best practice for creating the HTTP server.